# How saving data rows using loop form to save data in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save data from input form using django 3.0.3 throw loop form, the problem is when i enter the data into form only the second row saved and repeated in database.

This is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class NumberOfStudent(models.Model):
    class_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num_of_student = models.IntegerField()
    student_abscence = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_num
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import NumberOfStudent
from .forms import Insertdata


def home(request):
    # Number of class's room for Grade 11
    num_class_11 = 2

    # Check if method of from is post
    if request.method == 'POST':
        insertdata = Insertdata(request.POST)
        # Chck if data inserted is valid
        if insertdata.is_valid():
            for instance in range(num_class_11):
                instance = insertdata.save(commit=False)
                instance.pk = None
                instance.save()
            return redirect(data)

    else:
        insertdata = Insertdata()

    context = {
        'title': 'Home Page',
        'num_class_11': num_class_11,
        'range': range(num_class_11),
        'insertdata': insertdata,

    }
    return render(request, 'hello/home.html', context)


def data(request):
    class_11 = NumberOfStudent.objects.all()

    context = {
        'class_11': class_11,
    }
    return render(request, 'hello/data.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import NumberOfStudent


class Insertdata(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NumberOfStudent
        fields = ('class_num', 'num_of_student', 'student_abscence')
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> | <a href="{% url 'data' %}">Data</a>
    </div>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>

            {% for class in range %}
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" name="class_num" id="class_num" value="11/{{forloop.counter}}" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="num_of_student" id="num_of_student">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="student_abscence" id="student_abscence">
                </td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**data.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> | <a href="{% url 'data' %}">Data</a>
    </div>

    <table border="1" width="500px">
        <thead style="text-align: center; background-color: bisque;">
            <tr>
                <td>Class</td>
                <td>Total number</td>
                <td>Abscence</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for data in class_11 %}
        <tbody style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
                <td>{{data.class_num}}</td>
                <td>{{data.num_of_student}}</td>
                <td>{{data.student_abscence}}</td>
                <td>{{data.date}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

[I entered different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnYAU.png)

[The result repeated only the second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36SeE.png)

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: First you have multiple elements with the same id attribute and this is wrong.
Second, the name attribute of repeated fields should be suffixed with `[]`. For example `class_num[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because you have created an iterative loop and it iterates twice (for example) 
and each time you enter information coming from the user
But any information ?
You created an entry form and took some information for the same field in a duplicate way. this means, you have modified the value of the first field with the new value that you took in the second field and then the iterative cycle starts :"D

Try this (i have tried it and it is work)

## views.html

```
def home(request):
    num_class_11 = 2
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for instance in range(num_class_11):
           # getting value of input for each round of loop 
            num_of_studentINPUT = request.POST.get('num_of_student-'+str(instance))

            student_abscenceINPUT = request.POST.get('student_abscence-'+str(instance))

            class_numINPUT = request.POST.get('class_num-'+str(instance))

            createObj = NumberOfStudent.objects.create(
            num_of_student = num_of_studentINPUT,
            student_abscence = student_abscenceINPUT,
            class_num = class_numINPUT,
            )
            createObj.save()
        return redirect(data)

else:
    insertdata = Insertdata()

context = {
    'title': 'Home Page',
    'num_class_11': num_class_11,
    'range': range(num_class_11),
    'insertdata': insertdata,

}
return render(request, 'App/home.html', context)
enter code here
```

## home.html

```
{% for class in range %}
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="class_num-{{class}}" id="class_num" value="11/{{class}}" 
    readonly>
  </td>

  <td>
   <input type="text" name="num_of_student-{{class}}" id="num_of_student">
   </td>

   <td>
   <input type="text" name="student_abscence-{{class}}" id="student_abscence">
   </td>
 </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank's brother,
It work correctly now.
I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that your html forms is using the save form fields to send the two rows, and this way overwriting one with the other.

That means, in index.html, you are not using the class variable defined `{% for class in range %}` anywhere, and specifically not to define the form fields that will be sent.

(Note: there may be other issues, but that seems to be the first one to solve.)